# Will double-clicking install OS replace contents of the disk?

Tags: macos, mac

Will double-clicking install OS replace contents of the disk? In other words, if I want to do a clean install of Mavericks can I just double-click the downloaded file and perform the install? Will it automatically replace the contents or will I have to erase it first?

Comment: is this an executable, or an iso file?

Comment: It's says Install OS X Mavericks.app if that helps

Comment: ah, ok. Then that has a higher likelyhood of working than the alternative, but i'm not that familar with osx. I'm assuming that 1 of 2 things will happen: 1) it will automatically upgrade [aka, keep your files but upgrade the OS] or 2) give you the option to upgrade or clean install. Can't gaurentee any of this though